# Editing Parcel Fabric in Versioned Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, parcel-fabric

We keep our parcel fabric in a SDE database with an intermediate staging version that multiple users post changes to from their own personal edit versions.

We're able to edit the parcel fabric directly on the intermediate version, but when users try to edit the fabric on their own version, the parcel editing tools remain deactivated. Everyone can successfully edit and post any of the other feature classes in the database.

Is it possible to edit the fabric within these personal versions?

Version tree:

- Default

  - QA

    - User 1
    - User 2
    - User 3